# Mongo DB concurrency issue with findOne and updateOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

I am having an issue with concurrent requests that are updating the same document. I'm not using `findAndModify()` because I need to access the current state of the document to make the update which I don't see supported with `findAndModify()`. I also would like to avoid using `db.fsyncLock()` since that locks the entire database and I only need to lock one document in one collection.

First I use `findOne()` to get a document, then I use the `updateOne()` in the callback of `findOne()` to update the same document. When I queue up a bunch of actions and run them all at once I believe they are all accessing the same state when they call `findOne()` instead of waiting for the `updateOne()` to complete from the previous action.

How should I handle this?

```
mongoDBPromise.then((db)=> {
    db.collection("notes").findOne(
        {path: noteId},
        (err, result)=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            if (!result.UndoableNoteList.future.length) {
                console.log("Nothing to redo");
                return;
            }

            let past = result.UndoableNoteList.past.concat(Object.assign({},result.UndoableNoteList.present));
            let present = Object.assign({},result.UndoableNoteList.future[0]);
            let future = result.UndoableNoteList.future.slice(1, result.UndoableNoteList.future.length);

            db.collection("notes").updateOne(
                {path: noteId},
                {
                    $set: {
                        UndoableNoteList: {
                            past: past,
                            present: present,
                            future:future
                        }
                    }
                },
                (err, result)=> {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to sequentially run the queries using purely mongodb functions. I've written some node.js logic that blocks mongodb queries from running on the same document and adds those queries to a queue. Here's what the code currently looks like.

The Websocket Undo Listener

```
module.exports = (noteId, wsHelper, noteWebSocket) => {
    wsHelper.addMessageListener((msg, ws)=> {
        if (msg.type === "UNDO") {
            noteWebSocket.broadcast(msg, noteWebSocket.getOtherClientsInPath(noteId, wsHelper));
            noteWebSocket.saveUndo(noteId);
        }
    });
};
```

The `saveUndo` function called from the listener

```
saveUndo(noteId) {
    this.addToActionQueue(noteId, {payload: noteId, type: "UNDO"});
    this.getNoteByIdAndProcessQueue(noteId);
}
```

The `getNoteByIdAndProcessQueue` function called from saveUndo

```
    getNoteByIdAndProcessQueue(noteId) {
        if (this.isProcessing[noteId])return;
        this.isProcessing[noteId] = true;
        mongoDBPromise.then((db)=> {
            db.collection("notes").findOne(
                {path: noteId},
                (err, result)=> {
                    if (err) {
                        this.isProcessing[noteId] = false;
                        this.getNoteByIdAndProcessQueue(noteId);
                        return;
                    }

                    this.processQueueForNoteId(noteId, result.UndoableNoteList);
                });
        });
    }
```

The `processQueueForNoteId` function

```
processQueueForNoteId(noteId, UndoableNoteList) {

    this.actionQueue[noteId].forEach((action)=> {
        if (action.type === "UNDO") {
            UndoableNoteList = this.undoNoteAction(UndoableNoteList);
        } else if (action.type === "REDO") {
            UndoableNoteList = this.redoNoteAction(UndoableNoteList);
        } else if (action.type === "ADD_NOTE") {
            UndoableNoteList = this.addNoteAction(UndoableNoteList, action.payload);
        } else if (action.type === "REMOVE_NOTE") {
            UndoableNoteList = this.removeNoteAction(UndoableNoteList, action.payload);
        }
    });

    let actionsBeingSaved = this.actionQueue[noteId].concat();
    this.actionQueue[noteId] = [];
    mongoDBPromise.then((db)=> {
        db.collection("notes").updateOne(
            {path: noteId},
            {
                $set: {
                    UndoableNoteList: UndoableNoteList
                }
            },
            (err, result)=> {
                this.isProcessing[noteId] = false;

                // If the update failed then try again
                if (err) {
                    console.log("update error")
                    this.actionQueue[noteId] = actionsBeingSaved.concat(this.actionQueue[noteId]);
                }

                // if action were queued during save then save again
                if (this.actionQueue[noteId].length) {
                    this.getNoteByIdAndProcessQueue(noteId);
                }
            }
        )
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `updateOne()` is an async call, `findOne()` won't wait for it to complete and hence there can be situations where the same document is updated simultaneously, which won't be allowed in mongo.

I think `updateOne()` is not necessary in this case. ***Note that you have already found the right instance of the document which needs to be updated in `findOne()` query***. Now, you can update that instance and save that document without doing `updateOne()`. I think the problem can be avoided this way:

```
mongoDBPromise.then((db)=> {
    db.collection("notes").findOne(
        {path: noteId},
        (err, result)=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            if (!result.UndoableNoteList.future.length) {
                console.log("Nothing to redo");
                return;
            }

            let past = result.UndoableNoteList.past.concat(Object.assign({},result.UndoableNoteList.present));
            let present = Object.assign({},result.UndoableNoteList.future[0]);
            let future = result.UndoableNoteList.future.slice(1, result.UndoableNoteList.future.length);
            result.UndoableNoteList.past = past;
            result.UndoableNoteList.present = present;
            result.UndoableNoteList.future = future;

            //save the document here and return
        }
    );
});
```

Hope this answer helps you!

Comment: When I remove the updateOne then the doc isn't saved. I currently have a solution in place where I queue up the db calls and do one at a time, but it'd be nice if the db managed this queue

Comment: of course, it won't be saved, unless you call `result.save()` explicitly. But again, `result.save()` can happen simultaneously for same documents if the requests are spawned parallelly.

Comment: The result object is just a plain object with my data. Calling `result.save()` gives me the following error `TypeError: result.save is not a function`